# Serialize incoming JSON with dynamically changing fields

Tags: android, json, serialization, dynamic, gson

I have fields in the JSON response that change dynamically.

A part of the structure of the response remains constant so I can define a POJO for those fields, but I'm trying to serialize the rest of the response (that is within a JSON object with the key "fields") as a JSONObject. But when I log the JSONObject its always empty. The POJO is given below :

```
public class Project {

    @SerializedName("projectid")
    public String mProjectId;
    @SerializedName("parentgroupid")
    public String mParentGroupId;
    @SerializedName("projectname")
    public String mProjectName;
    @SerializedName("formid")
    public String mFormId;
    @SerializedName("state")
    public String mState;
    @SerializedName("priority")
    public int mPriority;
    @SerializedName("headers")
    public ArrayList<Header> mHeaders;
    @SerializedName("fields")
    public JSONObject mFields;
}
```

mFields is always returned as an empty JSONObject.

How do I serialize this dynamically changing JSONObject(Its key remains the same, but the contents change)?

Comment: are you getting respopnse from retrofit ?? then try to use `JsonObject` instead of `JSONObject ` and check

Comment: Perfect! Works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `JsonObject` instead of `JSONObject` and check.

as JsonObject can use the Object definition to directly create an object of the desired type and it is best for JSON parsing on Android, while JSONObject needs to be parsed manually.

For more details about its method and properties, please refer this [JsonObject](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

If using Retrofit, use JsonObject instead of JSONObject.